# html input type name like array AmountMap[1] value is not able to set <input type="textbox" size="15" name="amountMap[1]" value="0" >

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**html input type name like array AmountMap[1] value is not able to set

```
 <input type="textbox" size="15" name="amountMap[1]" value="0" >  
trying to set amountMap[1].value='10' get error - Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property '1' of undefined**
```

Comment: Plesse read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this will help you get your question answered quickly and more responses.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you are saying, you are saying.

When you do `first.value = 10`  it works, however when you do `second[1].value` it doesn't work.

if "first" does work. It's because it is an object. you can create objects by `let first = {}`

if "second" doesn't work its because you need an array of objects. You can do that by `let second = [ {}, {} ]`  and then your assignment should work.

Upvote if this helps :)

Comment: let amountMap = {};
amountMap[1]=20 ;

Comment: ? What does that mean

Comment: that way , i am able to create dynamic size array
let amountMap = {};
 amountMap[1]=10 ;
 amountMap[2]=20 ;
.........................
 amountMap[10]=100 ;